# How can I get dynamic navbar links in Vuepress 2?

Tags: vuejs3, vuepress

**TL;DR**

I am using Vuepress 2 for documentation, and I want to control dynamically, based on user roles, what links that are visible in the navbar. How can I do that?

**More details**

The thing I want to achieve is that some pages shall only be visible to some users. I have managed to control this on page level like this:

- On each page I have frontmatter with a list of roles that can access the page.
- In clientAppEnhance I fetch the users roles from an API.
- I have a plugin that in `onPrepare` creates a temp-file with a list of all pages and what roles that can access them (based on the frontmatter)
- In clientAppEnhance, I add a `route.beforeEach` function that verifies that the user has access to the page before loading it.

So on page level it works. However, I also want to show only links to allowed pages in the navbar and sidebar. I haven't looked at the sidebar yet, but I have tried to get this working in navbar without success.

I can use a function to return the navbar in the `config.js` file, but this function runs before the `onGenerated` function, so the temp-file is not yet created. I need `app.pages` to generate the temp file, but that is not available in the function that creates the navbar.

So, are there any ideas out there to how I can do this?

Comment: Did you figure this out Otto? I am looking for something similar to have multiple headers based on url

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

```
import { defineClientConfig } from '@vuepress/client'
import {homeNavbar} from "./theme/config/home";
import {quasarNavbar} from "./theme/config/frontend/quasar";

export default defineClientConfig({
    enhance({ app, router }) {

        router.afterEach((to) => {

            if (to.path === '/') {
                app.config.globalProperties.$theme.navbar = homeNavbar
            }

            if (to.path.includes('/frontend/quasar')) {
                app.config.globalProperties.$theme.navbar = quasarNavbar
            }

        })
    }
})
```

Source: https://github.com/vuepress/vuepress-next/discussions/1295